# Can't use await in generic Vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, generics, async-await, vuejs3

I have the below component, which is working fine, but I would like to make it generic by adding `generic="T"` to the `<script>`, e.g.

```
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
    import type LookupApiClient from "@/js/api/lookupApiClient";
    import { ref } from "vue";

    const props = defineProps<{
        label: string;
        rules: any[];
        apiClient: LookupApiClient<T>;
    }>();
```

But after adding this line,

```js
const response = await props.apiClient.lookup();
```

I get this error in VS Code:

> 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

my component:

```html
<template>
    <v-autocomplete
        v-model="selectedItem"
        :loading="isLoading"
        :items="items"
        :label="label ?? 'Search'"
        return-object
        :rules="rules"
        :hide-no-data="true"
        :item-title="(x: any) => x.name" />
</template>
```

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import type LookupApiClient from "@/js/api/lookupApiClient";
    import { ref } from "vue";

    const props = defineProps<{
        label: string;
        rules: any[];
        apiClient: LookupApiClient<any>;
    }>();
    
    const selectedItem = defineModel<any>({ required: true });
    const items = ref<any[]>([]);
    const isLoading = ref<boolean>(false);
    
    isLoading.value = true;
    
    const response = await props.apiClient.lookup(); 
    items.value = response;
    
    isLoading.value = false;
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check how it really works, apart from VS Code? The problem likely can be narrowed down to either IDE or compiler. Either way, I doubt something can be done besides keeping the relevant packages up to date